# Debouncing not working with React-Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash

I'm building a function that performs an API request on keypress, but I want this debounced.

This doesn't currently work and produces an error: `lodash.js:10319 Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function`

Here's a code snippet with a console log instead of async request, which also doesn't work!

```
import React from 'react';
const _ = require('lodash');

const method = () => {
    return _.debounce(testFunc(), 3000);
};

const testFunc = () => {
    console.log('echo echo test test');
};


const SearchBox = ({ onTypingSearch, searchTerm }) => (
    <form>
        <p>Search: {searchTerm}</p>
        <input
            onChange={(e) => {
                console.log(e.target.value);                
                onTypingSearch(e.target.value);
                console.log(method);
                method();
            }}
                value={searchTerm}
        />
  </form>
);

export default SearchBox;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to debounce the function, not the result of calling it:

This:

```
const method = () => {
    return _.debounce(testFunc(), 3000);
};
```

To this:

```
const method = () => {
    return _.debounce(testFunc, 3000);
};
```

Update:

The way you have set this up, `method` returns a debounced function.  So calling `method()` will return a function.  Then you will have to call it: `method()()`.

It is better to do this:

```
const method = _.debounce(() => {
    return testFunc();
}, 3000);
```

And if you want args:

```
const method = _.debounce((e) => {
    return testFunc(e);
}, 3000);
```

Then, you can continue calling the way you are doing at the moment: `method()`.

Comment: I tried that but then my function doesn't get executed?

Comment: Also how would you then pass an argument through to the function if you needed to?

Comment: From the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#debounce): `The func is invoked with the last arguments provided to the debounced function`

Comment: Great thanks, declaring a function from another function is a bit unfamiliar to me